# CNAME domain to heroku app

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I've got a domain hosted (DNS only) on Dreamhost. I've got www.mydomain.com CNAME'd to my web app on heroku, I would also like to CNAME just the domain (mydomain.com). Ofcourse, you can only CNAME subdomains.

What should I do to make mydomain.com point to my heroku app, or even redirect to www.mydomain.com?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Heroku's [documentation on the matter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords) references DNSimple's [ALIAS records](http://blog.dnsimple.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-alias-that-works/). If Dreamhost doesn't offer something similar, you'll need to run a small server handling the apex record, use a service like wwwizer.com, or switch DNS providers to one like DNSimple.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a great write](http://robandlauren.com/2013/02/21/pointing-a-dreamhost-domain-to-heroku/) up on how to work around Dreamhost's setup to use custom domains for your Heroku App.

Basically you create a www cname with the value of your custom heroku app address, then you redirect your @ root traffic to your www sub-domain.